# Error running Sql Assembly

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008, assemblies

I have a .net assembly build in to sql. It works on all other sql servers, except on one system I get this error.

```
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "GetCustomerData": 
System.IO.FileLoadException: The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
System.IO.FileLoadException: 
   at System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.Initialize()
   at System.Net.Logging.InitializeLogging()
   at System.Net.Logging.get_On()
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(Uri address)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(String address)
   at CustFromPhone.BaseFunctionClass.GetCustInfo(SqlString PhoneNo)
```

Comment: I restarted the sqlserver and recreated the assembly, and it works.
I don't delete the question because I want to know what this error means in case it happens again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply have wrong manifest data for your .NET binaries

> An assembly manifest contains all the metadata needed to specify the
>   assembly's version requirements and security identity, and all
>   metadata needed to define the scope of the assembly and resolve
>   references to resources and classes.
>   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifest_%28.NET_Framework%29

This is why its corrected when you rebuild it.